# Android device as BLE central and read/write operations without any trigger from peripheral

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

My Android app is made as a BLE central device. I have a device which is peripheral. I want to send some data from Android app to peripheral device without any request from the peripheral. Can I achieve this ?

In my peripheral device to write data i am using below code :

```
BluetoothGattCharacteristic charac = Service
            .getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.LOCAL_TIME));
byte[] value = new byte[1];
    String valuetosend = "data from client to server";
    value = valuetosend.getBytes();
    charac.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);
    charac.setValue(value);


    Log.d("BluetoothLeservice::","Write Status:" + charac.getValue());
    boolean status = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(charac);
```

Do I have to do in the same way for central also? Any reference links would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the process is same, you have to write data to the particular characteristic and service. You should know the value of the characteristic and service. In your case it is `SampleGattAttributes.LOCAL_TIME`.

Comment: Thank you. But I am confused like what is the difference between Central and peripheral in terms of coding ? because scanning is done in same way, write/read is also done in the same way.

Comment: Actually peripherals cannot scan central devices, also peripherals cannot connect to central devices. Centrals act like masters, so they have to initiate the connection process. Only similarity is I guess read and write operations. I haven't done coding in Android Studio, I work on hybrid applications using cordova and ionic, so I cannot tell you the code exactly.

Comment: Ok thanks. I guess I have mistaken. Now I have the clarity. Do you have any reference link which says this ? Please share

Comment: This may help you: Link: [BLE roles](http://embedded.fm/blog/ble-roles).

Comment: I have another problem. Connecting to a device is taking more time. Most of the time it takes multiple retry options. What might be the reason ?